# t-sql - delete second value only

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i would like to run a sql statement that will delete ONLY the second value for example

```
delete from table1 where condition1
```

i want this statement to delete ONLY the second value

how can i accomplish this?

i would like to clarify. i have a field called `field1` which is an autonumber and and it is a primary key and it increments. i would like to delete the record containing the greater number

Comment: How do you determine which value comes "first" and which value comes "second"?

Comment: Is this meant to clean out duplicate entries? That's sort of what it looks like.

Comment: @anon thank you i have clarified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also employ the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function of SQL server to number each row, and use this number to isolate just the second item for deletion, according to your own custom ordering in the inner query ( `over (ORDER BY <myKey> asc)` ). This provides a great deal of flexibility.

```
DELETE a FROM table1 
FROM table1 a 
JOIN (
        select ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY <myKey> asc) as AutoNumber, <myKey> from table1
) b on a.<myKey> = b.<myKey>
WHERE condition1
AND b.AutoNumber = 2
```

Comment: The self join isn't needed here. [You can delete from the CTE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows/3822833#3822833)

Comment: @Martin: Good point - I always forget about CTE's, sometimes the syntax can be quite confusing though, this example is easier to digest IMHO.

Comment: Digest? You're executing it not eating it! The delete from the CTE without the self join is more efficient.

Comment: The food for the mind is knowledge and more importantly understanding(something a CTE may negate)...so yes; `digest` is an apt figure of speech in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to delete only the last duplicate, or all but the first?

For all but the first: (**Edited** to use CTE per @Martin's suggestion.)

```
with target as (select * from table1 where condition1)
delete from target goner
 where exists (select * from target keeper
                where keeper.field1 < goner.field1)
```

In other words, if there is another matching record with a lower field1, delete this record.

**EDIT:**
To delete only the last:

```
with target as (select * from table1 where condition1)
delete from target goner
 where exists (select * from target keeper
                where keeper.field1 < goner.field1)
   and not exists (select * from target missing
                    where missing.field1 > goner.field1)
```

In other words, if there is another matching record with a lower field1, AND there is no matching record with a higher field1, then we have the highest duplicate, so nuke it.

Comment: I don't think this works.  SQL: `WITH TEMP as
(
  SELECT 1 as id,'A' as a,'Z' as b
  UNION
  SELECT 2,'A','Z'
  UNION
  SELECT 3,'B','Z'
  UNION
  SELECT 4,'B','Z'
)

SELECT * from TEMP
 where id > 0 
   and exists (select * from TEMP other
                where other.id > 0 
                  and other.id < TEMP.id)`

Comment: Notice that it selects 2,3 AND 4.

Comment: @Martin:  Touché.  It's possible that condition1 is a long, obnoxious expression, and we want to keep the code DRY.  Shortens the query by a line too.

Comment: You only want to nuke the last one, and leave 1, 2, and 3 alone?  Okay.

Comment: @Jeffrey - Touché Indeed! I didn't actually mean like that though. I meant [instead of any kind of explicit join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows/3822833#3822833)

Comment: @Martin: Fair enough.  I hadn't considered ROW_NUMBER() -- I was trying to approach it from a set-theoretic point of view, so I tend to miss techniques like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE MyTable 
FROM MyTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(id) as id, Col1, Col2, Col3 
   FROM MyTable 
   GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3
) as KeepRows ON
   MyTable.id= KeepRows.id
WHERE
   KeepRows.RowId IS NULL
```

**UPDATE**

While this might not be as "pretty" as @Jeffrey's it works.  From what I can tell, @Jeffrey's does not.  See sql below (Delete replaced with `SELECT *` for demonstration):

```
WITH TEMP as
(
  SELECT 1 as id,'A' as a,'Z' as b
  UNION
  SELECT 2,'A','Z'
  UNION
  SELECT 3,'B','Z'
  UNION
  SELECT 4,'B','Z'
)

SELECT *
FROM TEMP
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(id) as id, a, b
   FROM TEMP 
   GROUP BY a, b
) as KeepRows ON
   temp.id= KeepRows.id
WHERE
   KeepRows.id IS NULL
```

Comment: DELETE MyTable 
FROM MyTable ??

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while (so my syntax my not quite be right), and this may not be the best solution, but the "academic" answer would be something like:

```
delete from table1 where condition1
and field1 = (select max(field1) from table1 where condition1)
```